# How can I process opcodes stored in a binary file in Perl?

Tags: perl, binary

*[Creating Your Own Abstract Processor](http://packetstormsecurity.org/files/105938/Abstract-Processor.pdf)* is a quick paper on what I am trying to do.

http://malcon.org/ctm.rar is the exact specifications on what the emulator should be.

I am writing a sort of an emulator in Perl. This program will read in a binary file and process the hex of the binary into actions, how a processor works, but software based with different opcodes. Just a challenge thing.

Anyhow, I am not entirely sure how to read the binary file into an array and then assign the hex from the array to the opcodes. This is part of my code:

```
my $opcode='';
my $file= "path/to/file";
my $IP=0;
my $SP=0;
my $FLAG=0;
my $A=0;
my $B=0;
my $X=0;
my @STACK=(0);

open(F, "<".$file) || die("Could not open file");
binmode(F);
my @ROM = <F>;
close(F);

while($IP >= 0)
{
    $opcode="$ROM[$IP]";
    if ($opcode eq 11) {
        $A = $STACK[$SP];
        $IP++;
    }
    if ($opcode eq 12) {
        $B = $STACK[$SP];
        $IP++;
    }
    if ($opcode eq 13) {
        $A = $B;
        $IP++;
    }
    if ($opcode eq 14) {
        $B = $A;
        $IP++;
    }
```

This is just the part of the code I need help with. If you need to see more of it for some reason, just let me know.

So I changed my code to reflect an answer above, my code now looks like this:

```
my $opcode='';
my $file= "CTM-bootrom";
my $IP=0;
my $SP=0;
my $FLAG=0;
my $A=0;
my $B=0;
my $X=0;
my @STACK=(0);

open my $ROM, '<:raw', $file or die "Cannot open '$file': $!";

{
    local $/ = \1; # Read one byte at a time
    while (my $byte = <$ROM>){
        while($IP >= 0)
        {
            $opcode=$ROM[$IP];
            if ($opcode eq 11) {
                $A = $STACK[$SP];
                $IP++;
            }
            if ($opcode eq 12) {
                $B = $STACK[$SP];
                $IP++;
            }
            if ($opcode eq 13) {
                $A = $B;
                $IP++;
            }
```

But now I get an error:

> Use of uninitialized value $opcode in string eq at Aod8.pl line 73,

<$ROM> to me it looks like opcode is initialized... How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The link http://malcon.org/ctm.rar is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now...everything is now working like needed:

```
my $IP=0;
my $FLAG=0;
my $SP=0;
my $A=0;
my $B=0;
my @STACK=(0);
my $byte=0;
$| = 1;

open(BOOTROM, "<bootrom.txt");
binmode(BOOTROM);

my (@ROM, $instruction);
while ((read BOOTROM, $instruction, 1) != 0) {
    @ROM[$IP] = $instruction;
    $IP++;
}
close(BOOTROM);

$IP = 0;
while ($IP >= 0 && $byte != 0x3C) {
    $byte = ord(@ROM[$IP]);

    if ($byte == 0x11) {
        $A = (@STACK[$SP]);
        $IP++;
    }
    elsif ($byte == 0x12) {
        $B = (@STACK[$SP]);
        $IP++;
    }
    elsif ($byte == 0x13) {
        $A = $B;
        $IP++;
    }
    elsif ($byte == 0x14) {
        $B = $A;
        $IP++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't necessarily think it is a good idea to read the binary one character at a time (although, for small enough files, you'll be fetching from a buffer most of the time). Conceptually, reading the file into a flat array is better. You can get that by using

```
my @ROM = do {
    local $/ = \1;
    map ord, <$fh>;
};
```

I think that answers the gist of your question.

Now, as for the idea of not reading the entire file into an array, but using the file itself as the executable image, here is a little script I wrote based on earlier versions of this post and feedback.

Please note that the whole scalar filehandle thing is there to provide scaffolding for running ROMs included in the article you linked by copying and pasting instead of having to create binary files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Fcntl ':seek';
use Try::Tiny;

my %ROMS = (

    rom1 => [0x04, 0x41, 0x09, 0x02, 0x0a],

    rom2 => [
        0x04, 0x41, 0x09, 0x02,
        0x07, 0x09, 0x02, 0x07,
        0x09, 0x02, 0x07, 0x09,
        0x02, 0x07, 0x09, 0x02,
        0x0A,
    ],

    rom3 => [
        0x04,   69, 0x09, 0x02, 0x04,  110, 0x09, 0x02,
        0x04,  116, 0x09, 0x02, 0x04,  101, 0x09, 0x02,
        0x04,  114, 0x09, 0x02, 0x04,   32, 0x09, 0x02,
        0x04,   97, 0x09, 0x02, 0x04,   32, 0x09, 0x02,
        0x04,   67, 0x09, 0x02, 0x04,  104, 0x09, 0x02,
        0x04,   97, 0x09, 0x02, 0x04,  114, 0x09, 0x02,
        0x04,   32, 0x09, 0x02, 0x04,   58, 0x09, 0x02,
        0x04,   32, 0x09, 0x02, 0x04,   50, 0x03, 0x01,
        0x04,    2, 0x03, 0x04,   89, 0x09, 0x02, 0x04,
         111, 0x09, 0x02, 0x04,  117, 0x09, 0x02, 0x04,
         32,  0x09, 0x02, 0x04,   84, 0x09, 0x02, 0x04,
         121, 0x09, 0x02, 0x04,  112, 0x09, 0x02, 0x04,
         101, 0x09, 0x02, 0x04,  100, 0x09, 0x02, 0x04,
          32, 0x09, 0x02, 0x04,   58, 0x09, 0x02, 0x04,
          32, 0x09, 0x02, 0x04,   50, 0x03, 0x02, 0x0A,
    ]

);

for my $rom (sort keys %ROMS) {
    my $rom_s = join '', map chr, @{ $ROMS{ $rom } };

    open my $rom_h, '<:raw', \$rom_s
        or die "Cannot open handle to ROM string: $!\n";

    print "Executing $rom\n";

    try {
        execute($rom_h);
    }
    catch {
        print "\n$rom: $_\n";
    };

    close $rom_h
        or die "Cannot close handle to ROM string: $!\n";
}

sub get_next_byte {
    my ($fh) = @_;
    my $byte = do {
        local $/ = \1;
        scalar <$fh>;
    };

    return unless defined $byte;

    $byte = ord $byte;

    return $byte;
}

sub execute {
    my ($ROM) = @_;

    my $FLAG = 0;
    my $SP = 0;
    my $X = 0;
    my @STACK;

    my @machine = (

        # NOP
        sub {},

        # INPUT
        sub { $STACK[$SP] = ord(getc STDIN) },

        # OUTPUT
        sub { printf STDOUT '%c', $STACK[$SP] },

        # MOV SP, X
        sub { $SP = $X },

        # MOV X, DATA
        sub {
            $X = get_next_byte($ROM);
        },

        # CMP X, DATA
        sub {
            $FLAG = $X - get_next_byte($ROM);
        },

        # JE
        sub {
            my $offset = get_next_byte($ROM);

            if ($FLAG == 0) {
                seek $ROM, $offset, SEEK_CUR
            }
        },

        # INC X
        sub { $X += 1 },

        # INC SP
        sub { $SP += 1 },

        # MOV [SP], X
        sub { $STACK[$SP] = $X },

        # HALT
        sub {
            die "HALT\n";
        },
    );

    while (1) {
        my $opcode = get_next_byte($ROM);

        last unless defined $opcode;

        if (($opcode >= 0) and ($opcode < @machine)) {
            $machine[ $opcode ]->();
        }
        else {
            die sprintf(
                "Invalid opcode '%02x' at offset '%x'\n",
                $opcode, $.,
            );
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
Executing rom1
A
rom1: HALT

Executing rom2
ABCDE
rom2: HALT

Executing rom3
Enter a Char : d
You Typed : d
rom3: HALT
```

Comment: Quite the opposite, he does need the whole file to be loaded; he's just loading it wrong.

Comment: Why can't the ROM be on disk?

Comment: Memery accessed linearly. If you want to do a seek before each read, go ahead, but it's definitely a waste. And then there's the case that the ROM wouldn't be very read-only if you didn't make a copy of it into RAM. Did you forget about store operations?

Comment: I see you added a dispatch table. I'm not sure that's the best approach. If any thought went into his virtual machine, the opcode isn't indicated by the whole byte. Most of the bits of the byte are actually the operands (i.e. data). There are really only 12 opcodes or so.

Comment: s/Memery accessed linearly./Memory isn't accessed linearly./

Comment: You forgot to turn the character into a number.

Comment: @ikegami Yup, I forgot an `ord`, fine. The program is linear: I really don't have to seek other than when dealing with jump instructions. I see now the OP posted a link. One might have to be careful with the `input` and `output` instructions, but otherwise, reading from a file (or even a filehandle on a scalar) is probably fine and would be instructive for the OP to try out. That's the spirit in which this post is offered. If I were writing this, I would have written an assembler, or, at the least permitted nicely formatted hexdumps as input. At least, that's what we used to do in '82.

Comment: Re "That's the spirit in which this post is offered.", No, and that was my point. He was trying to use `$ROM[$IP]`, and you suggested this wasn't the way to go. Yet, it has numerous advantages. And reading from the file has numerous disadvantages.

Comment: I actually tried using a hex dump, but the dump is like 70 pages of hex lol

Answer (score 1):

If `$opcode` is undef, then `$ROM[$IP]` is undef.

In the second version of the code, you didn't show `@ROM` being populated, so that's not surprising that `$ROM[$IP]` is undef then.

The first version of the code is closer to what you want. However, `@ROM` is incorrectly initialised. Each line of the file (which isn't even made of lines) is assigned to an element of `@ROM`, but you want each byte of the file to be assigned to an element of `@ROM`. This is done as follows:

```
my @ROM = do {
   open(my $fh, '<', $file)
      or die("Can't open ROM file \"$file\": $!\n");
   binmode($fh);
   local $/;  # Read entire file at once.
   map ord, split //, <$fh>
};
```

After fixing up the rest of the code, it looks like the following:

```
my @STACK;
my $A  = 0;
my $B  = 0;
my $SP = 0;
my $IP = 0;
for (;;) {
   die(sprintf("Bad address 0x%04X\n", $IP)) if $IP >= @ROM;
   my $instruction = $ROM[$IP++];

   if    ($opcode == 0x11) { $A = $STACK[$SP]; }
   elsif ($opcode == 0x12) { $B = $STACK[$SP]; }
   elsif ($opcode == 0x13) { $A = $B; }
   ...
   else { die(sprintf("Bad opcode 0x%02X\n", $opcode)); }
}
```

Note that `:raw` is not quite equivalent to `binmode` despite documentation to that effect.

Note the use or [`ord`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ord.html) to convert the chars into their numerical value, and the use of numerical comparison operators (`==`) to compare those numbers.

Note that I used hexadecimal numbers. Hex (or maybe octal depending on the machine being emulated) will be clearer than using decimal since similar opcodes tend to vary in bits, not digits. Furthermore, the numbers you were provider are already in hex, so opcode `11` is actually *seventeen*.

```
$char_from_file eq 11          # XXX What you had.
$char_from_file eq chr(0x11)   # Ok, but a bit suboptimal.
ord($char_from_file) == 0x11   # Ok. What I have.
```

Comment: http://packetstormsecurity.org/files/105938/Abstract-Processor.pdf   This is a quick paper on what I am trying to do.       http://malcon.org/ctm.rar                                          This is the exact specifications on what the emulator should be.

Comment: It does seem to have a separate stack. That's very unrealistic, but so be it. I've removed my comments regarding the stack.

Comment: @quantumdisaster, The opcode numbers are in hex in the PDF. so when you were comparing to eleven, you should have been comparing to seventeen (0x11). Adjusted my post.

Comment: @quantumdisaster, Whoever designed that machine doesn't know much about machine design. This would be very inefficient to implement in hardware.

Comment: the line     map ord, split    puts the data in my array as decimal numbers, i need them there as hex values

Comment: @quantumdisaster, Decimal and hex are ways of printing numbers; they're not numbers (seventeen), they're strings (17 or 11). `ord` returns a number. Your wrong about it being "decimal". You do want `ord`.

Comment: in the debugger when I look at the @ROM variable after it has been populated I am not seeing it as hex, I am seeing it as decimal. how would I get the if statements to check against the array then?

Comment: @quantumdisaster, Again, you're wrong about it beind decimal. It's neither stored as a decimal string nor as a hex string, it's stored a number. You're seeing the decimal representation of the number because you're using a command that prints the decimal representation of the number. Use a command that prints the hex representation of the number if that's what you want.

Comment: well i dump the @ROM (x @ROM) what returns in the debugger appears in decimal yes.

Comment: @quantumdisaster, What's your point? Don't use `x` if it doesn't produce the output you want.

Comment: the point is that it is supposed to be doing tests based on the value in the array. the value is supposed to be a hex value. I did this in python but want to do it in perl (just because)

Comment: @quantumdisaster, I'm getting tired of being contradicted with no basis or proof whatsoever. No, you don't want it to be a hex string, you want it to be a number to compare it. See the code I posted!!!

Comment: @quantumdisaster, `ord("\x11")` produces the number seventeen. `0x11` produces the number seventeen. If you compare them, they are equal. They are not stored in decimal (`17`) or even hex (`11`) they are stored as a 32-bit or 64-bit 2's complement signed integer, a format that resembles binary more than anything.

Comment: im not really contradicting you(except now) but you see how you read the binary file into memory...then you see how you test if $opcode == 0x11 etc...well the two do not mesh, its testing to see if the data in the array is equal to the opcode, but the data isn't being stored in that format

Comment: Sample from debugger:                                                               DB<2> x @ROM
0  26
1  9
2  54
3  21
4  58
5  26
6  31
7  54
8  21
9  58
10  26
11  31

Comment: @quantumdisaster, Clearly, I cannot help you. You are not listening or you do not understand me, you're making stuff up ("the two do not mesh"), and you're just repeating yourself endlessly (e.g. bringing up `x` again.). Good luck.

Comment: x is how you dump a variable in the perl debugger, i am not making anything up, they dont work together...guess you dont know how to do this either...thanks for your time

Comment: @quantumdisaster, You again lie about them not working together. (`perl -E"say ord(qq{\x11}) == 0x11 ? 1 : 0"`). We already covered that you shouldn't be using `x` if it doesn't give you the output format you want, yet you bring it up a third time.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want split the file byte by byte to `@ROM`, try

```
local $/; # get the whole file once, see perldoc perlvar for details
my @ROM = split //, <F>;
```